# Which groups have this property $(g_1 g_2)^{-1} = (g_1)^{-1} (g_2)^{-1}$?

Tags: group-theory

$G$ is a group and $g_{1} g_{2}\in G $.  Which groups have the property where $(g_1 g_2)^{-1} = (g_1)^{-1} (g_2)^{-1}$. Is there a group name to a group that can do this? For example, the group name for a group that is commutative is abelian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have that $(g_1g_2)^{-1} = g_2^{-1}g_1^{-1}$ since
$$
(g_1g_2)(g_2^{-1}g_1^{-1}) = e
$$
due to associativity.  Thus
$$
g_2^{-1}g_1^{-1} = g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1}
$$
for all $g_1,g_2 \in G$.  Since every group element is the inverse of its inverse, this is the same as being abelian.

Comment: Are you saying that $(g_1g_2)^{-1} = (g_2)^{-1}(g_1)^{-1}$ in general?

Comment: @PiccolMan Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $(g_1g_2)^{-1} = (g_1)^{-1}(g_2)^{-1}$ for all $g_1,g_2 \in G$. Then, for any $g,h \in G$ note that

$$ gh = gh(hg)^{-1}hg = gh (h^{-1} g^{-1}) hg = hg.$$

Thus, $G$ is abelian.  Conversely, if $G$ is abelian then for any $g,h \in G$:

$$ (gh)^{-1} = h^{-1}g^{-1}=  g^{-1} h^{-1}.$$

That is, we have proved that your criterion is an equivalent definition to $G$ being an abelian group.